# Expressing object states without a thousand optionals while avoiding "never" issue

Tags: typescript

I have issues with valid typescript while expressing objects that I use for state. My types are getting marked `never`. (I use redux and react, this is common).

For example here is my simplified `Session` interface (in reality I have a thousand optionals in here, but many of them don't exist until another field exists):

```
interface ISession {
  dismissedIntro: boolean;
  deviceId?: string;
  lastDeviceIdSyncAt?: number;
}
```

In here it's clear that `dismissedIntro` is always available as a boolean. The problem happens with optionals.

`deviceId` is fine as an optional because it can be given or not. But `lastDeviceIdSyncAt` is not ok. It can never be non-void unless `deviceId` is  a string. And it's not always present when `deviceId` is a string. So correct way would be:

```
type InitialSession = {
  dismissedIntro?: boolean;
  deviceId: void;
  lastDeviceIdSyncAt: void;
}

type FollowedPartialSession = { deviceId: string; lastDeviceIdSyncAt?: number }

type Session = InitialSession & FollowedSession;
```

Valid actual objects:

```
const state = { dismissedIntro: false };
const state = { dismissedIntro: true };
const state = { dismissedIntro: false, deviceId: 'foo' };
const state = { dismissedIntro: true, deviceId: 'foo' };
const state = { dismissedIntro: false, deviceId: 'foo', lastDeviceIdSyncAt: 1111111111 };
const state = { dismissedIntro: true, deviceId: 'foo', lastDeviceIdSyncAt: 1111111111 };
```

The problem is `Session` gets highlighted saying "never" type. Any typescript recomended ways to handle this problem?

Comment: Have you tried an union (|) instead of an intersection (&). `type Session = InitialSession 
| FollowedSession` will kind of allow you to check for one distinguishing property and switch on that.

Comment: @wegry thanks for that idea. Union is one or the other. It doesn't build on `InitialSession`. So `dismissedIntro` can be missing and typescrit will say its ok.